# Creating FullCalendar Custom Buttons in React

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

I am implementing FullCalendar using React and want to add custom buttons.  The FullCalendar docs cover custom buttons but not for React.

I've tried different variations of the custom button code shown in the docs but I can't get anything to work in React. I've put the custom button in an array.  I've tried moving the custom button code out of the render method.

```
export default class DemoApp extends React.Component {

  calendarComponentRef = React.createRef()
  state = {
    calendarWeekends: true,
    calendarEvents: [ // initial event data
      { title: 'Event Now', start: new Date() }
    ]
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='demo-app'>
        <div className='demo-app-top'>
          <button onClick={ this.toggleWeekends }>toggle weekends</button>&nbsp;
          <button onClick={ this.gotoPast }>go to a date in the past</button>&nbsp;
          (also, click a date/time to add an event)
        </div>
        <div className='demo-app-calendar'>
          <FullCalendar
            customButtons: {
                myCustomButton: {
                    text: 'custom!',
                    click: function() {
                        alert('clicked the custom button!');
                        }
                    }
            },
            defaultView="dayGridMonth"
            header={{
              left: 'prev,next today',
              center: 'title, myCustomButton'
              right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
            }}
            plugins={[ dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin ]}
            ref={ this.calendarComponentRef }
            weekends={ this.state.calendarWeekends }
            events={ this.state.calendarEvents }
            dateClick={ this.handleDateClick }
            />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

I am getting an error telling my that myCustomButton is undefined.

Comment: I'd expect you'd do it using the syntax you've used for all the other options, e.g. `header={` - so I asume it's got to be `customButtons={` . The syntax for the props seems fairly, clear - was there a particular reason you didn't follow that pattern?

Comment: I tried that and it did not work :(

Comment: show exactly what you tried please, then we can be sure of the precise situation. And when you tried, what was the error / output?

Comment: Looks like the specific issue is that you've got `customButtons: {` and you needed `customButtons={{` (an equals `=` and another set of surrounding brackets). Is that what you did to fix it?

Answer (score 8):

Add the following properties to the `FullCalendar` React component:

```
<FullCalendar
    ...
    customButtons={{
        myCustomButton: {
            text: 'custom!',
            click: function() {
                alert('clicked the custom button!');
            },
        },
    }},
    header={{
        left: 'prev,next today myCustomButton',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
    }}
    ...
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it like following, take a look of double curly braces this is because of React/JSX syntax:

```
...    
customButtons={{
                  myCustomButton: {
                    text: 'custom!',
                    click: function() {
                      alert('clicked the custom button!');
                    },
                  },
                }}
...
```