# Can I make a custom headerToolbar in react FullCalendar?

Tags: css, reactjs, fullcalendar

I have a good design about a calendar for my App. I want to customize the buttons and selectors inside of my FullCalendar component. I have some troubles to make that so here we go

[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEtlD.png)

I've tried with this:

```
 <StyleWrapper>
            <FullCalendar
                ref={calendarRef}
                plugins={[dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
                initialView="dayGridMonth"
                firstDay={1}
                events={events}
                headerToolbar={{
                    start: 'prev,  next, today',
                }}
                dayHeaderContent={(info) => <span className='custom-day-header'>{getDayInitial(info.date)}</span>}
            />
        </StyleWrapper>
```

And have my custom styles in the StyleWrapper container:

```
export const StyleWrapper = styled.div`
.fc-prev-button, .fc-next-button, .fc-today-button fc-button fc-button-primary {
    background-color: white !important; // Set your desired background color
    color: #FFF; // Set your desired text color
    border: 4px solid green !important; // Set your desired border color
    border-radius: 5px; // Set your desired border radius
    margin-right: 5px; // Adjust spacing if needed
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px 10px; // Adjust padding if needed
  }

  .custom-month-select-button {
    background-color: #your-color; // Set your desired background color
    color: #your-text-color; // Set your desired text color
    border: 1px solid #your-border-color; // Set your desired border color
    border-radius: 5px; // Set your desired border radius
    margin-right: 5px; // Adjust spacing if needed
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px 10px; // Adjust padding if needed
  }
`
```

That doesn't works with my expected results, anyways I want to add custom components like a row with my custom buttons and everything and doesn't works it displays like a small buttons like this:

[small buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18RtQ.png)

I've tested a solution like this [solution tested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56548754/creating-fullcalendar-custom-buttons-in-react)
but doesn't get the desired result because i want to add a selector and more functionally not only a single button.

Hope any solution for my problem, I'm not expert with React or CSS. Thanks